# Using jQuery To Add Class Based On URL

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery and I'm trying to add a class to a menu item based on URL. I tried this(found in other topics), but cannot get it to work properly. It adds the class to every menu item after the current page url.

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        switch (window.location.pathname) {
            case '/p/about.html':
                    $('.nav-about').addClass('current')
            case '/search/blog':
                    $('.nav-blog').addClass('current')
            case '/p/design.html':
                    $('.nav-design').addClass('current')
            case '/p/photography.html':
                $('.nav-photography').addClass('current')
            case '/p/hosting.html':
                $('.nav-hosting').addClass('current')
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Any help on correcting this?

Thanks.

EDIT: for those asking, I am using Blogger. Instead of using the default "Link-List", I created my own responsive menu. There is only one template here, so it's not like I can add a class to each HTML page. It's gonna have to be done with jQuery, because Blogger doesn't add specific classes to specific pages. So I need to grab the URL to apply the appropriate class to the appropriate menu item.

Comment: Why don't you do this from within your HTML?

Comment: I'm using Blogger, with a custom menu I made(responsive), rather than use the default link-list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `break` after each case or else it will just go on to the next one.

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/p/about.html':
       $('.nav-about').addClass('current');
       break;
    case '/search/blog':
       $('.nav-blog').addClass('current');
       break;
    case '/p/design.html':
       $('.nav-design').addClass('current');
       break;
    case '/p/photography.html':
       $('.nav-photography').addClass('current');
       break;
    case '/p/hosting.html':
       $('.nav-hosting').addClass('current');
       break;
}
```

---

Side point, this is repetitive:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
```

Both of those mean the same thing, use one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend giving your search links a class and doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var current = window.location.pathname;
   $('.search-link').each(function(){
      var link = '/' + $(this).attr('href');
      if (current == link){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      }
   }); 
});
```

This will compare the href of each link with the current pathname and add an active class if they match. The '/' in the link var is optional depending on whether or not it's already in the href.

The $(this).parent().addClass('active') adds an active class to the parent 'li' element if the path matches which works well with bootstrap, but where you want the class and what it's called will depend on your css.

Answer (score 2):

**If the element you're adding the `current` class to has a `href` value relative to the current page's URL this method will likely be easier for you.**

You could probably simplify this a bit..

Let's say you're on the following page: http://domain.com/page.html

```
var current_location = window.location.href.split('/'); // ['http:', '', '', 'domain.com', 'page.html']
var page;

page = current_location[current_location.length - 1]; // the length of the current_location array is 5, subtract one to get the value of the 4th index - which is page.html

$('a[href*="' + page + '"]').addClass('current'); // find a link on the page that links to page.html (current page) and add a class of `current` to this URL
```

Here's an example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uzoyis/1

Comment: What if the redirection is not occurring from an anchor tag? The URL is not necessarily inside the href of the element so you can't depend on finding it there.

Comment: You are correct. I assumed he was using anchors with `href` attributes.

Comment: and that's ok! Sometimes we really do have to guess! If you're making assumptions about some details that the OP might have left out, you should state so in your answer..

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a different suggestion. From the examples you have given, it would be very possible to extract the elements class from the URL itself:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var elementName = url.match(/\/(\w+)\.?\/?$/);
$('.nav-' + elementName).addClass('current');
```

The regular expression matches:

1. `\/` - a slash character (needs to be escaped).
2. `(\w+)` - more than one word character. This is also being "captured" and returned.
3. `\.?` - a literal dot character (needs to be escaped too). This is to match the begining of a file extension like`.php` or `.html`. The question mark makes it optional.
4. `\/?` - a literal slash character (needs to be escaped too). This is to match a trailing slash for URL's like `/members/`. The question mark makes it optional.
5. `$` - matches the end of a string.

The nav elements full class name is then made up from a concatenation of `.nav-` and what ever was matched and captured from the regular expression.

It really depends on the formatting of your URL's but for your example URL's this would work just fine. This code really allows you to by the DRY mindset - Don't Repeat Yourself.