# How can add class "Active" on click of an li element and remove it from others at the same time?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a menu in which I want to change the CSS of an li element on click while at the same time, CSS of other li's should remain the same.

My menu is:

```
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">non-link item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

and my jquery to add CSS to the selected element is:

```
 $("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

    });
```

However, right now, I am unable to remove the added CSS from a non-selected element. Is there anyway I can implement this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327080/using-jquery-to-add-class-based-on-url

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m72Z3/)

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
  $("#menu li").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ecAkEyok/2/)**

Answer (score 5):

Try this, this will always work

```
$("#menu li a").on('click', function(e){
    $("#menu .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for the javascript-free approach, you can use radio buttons:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/

and use the sibling selector to style them

```
input[type='radio']:checked + label
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kug8G/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu li a").click(function(){
    // Remove active if this does not have active class
    if(!($(this).closest("li").hasClass("active"))){
        $(this).closest("#menu").find("li.active").removeClass('selected');
    }
    $(this).closest("li").addClass('selected');
});
```