# Active link in menu with jQuery is not functioning

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following code in jQuery for adding class active to links in nav menu- jQuery

```
$('.main__menu li a').click(function(e){
        
        $('.main__menu li a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

but is not functioning, the code is adding active class but is not changing the html pages when clicking on a links because of e.preventDefault();

Has someone working code for this?

Comment: If you need to redirect the page after clicking the link, then amending the class before the redirection is redundant. You instead need to set the class on the `a` element relevant to the current page when the page itself is loaded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have you a working example, also when I set e.preventDefault(); at the top of inside of this function is not functioning.

Comment: @AlirezaMadad I did not downvote you. However I would have if I'd seen your answer that you deleted as it does not address the problem

Comment: @Ivana you need to follow a pattern similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16327080/519413 - assuming you can't do it server side, which would be a better solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, I am not doing it on server side because it is a simple web site with no backend language.

Answer (score 0):

**Add Style of hyper link**

```
<style>
    .main__menu li a {
        background-color: #cccccc;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .main__menu li a.active {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

**Html Code of Menu Item**

```
<nav class="main__menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="active">First Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Second Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Third Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fourth Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Jquery Code of Click event**

```
    
$('.main__menu > ul > li > a').click(function(e){   

        $('.main__menu > ul > li > a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();  
       
});
```

______________________________________________________

*note : jQuery code is using parent child relation ship of html element.

Comment: Sorry is not functioning this.

Comment: Please check Below file https://github.com/VijithP/SOQuestion/blob/main/menu.html

Answer (score 0):

The working code:

first add active class to index.html in html code:

```
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Homepage</a>
```

And Jquery code:

```
    var current_location = window.location.href.split('/'); // ['http:', '', '', 'domain.com', 'page.html']
    var page;
    page = current_location[current_location.length - 1];

    $('.main__menu li a').removeClass('active');
    $('.main__menu li a').each(function(){
        var link =  $(this).attr('href');

        if (page === link){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

@RoryMcCrossan thanks for adding hints! :)